# How to do not loose rows with NaN when stack/unstak?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a set of data running from 1945 to 2020, for a series of material produced in two countries. To create a dataframe I concat different df.

```
df = pd.concat([ProdCountry1['Producta'], [ProdCountry2['Producta'], [ProdCountry1['Productb'],  [ProdCountry2['Productb'], ...] ...)
```

With axis=1, the keys and names, etc.

I get this kind of table:

[image]

Then I stack this dataframe to get out the NaNs in rows index (years), but then I loose the years 1946/1948/1949, which are with NaNs only.

```
df = df.stack()
```

Here is the kind of df I get when I unstack it:

[image]

So, my question is: how can I avoid loosing the years with NaN rows in my df? I need them to interpolate and work later in my notebook.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a `dropna` parameter to the stack method pass it as `false`

```
 DataFrame.stack(level=- 1, dropna=True)
```

Cf Documentation for [pandas.DataFrame.stack](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html)

Answer (score 1):

Let us try `dropna`

```
df = df.dropna(how='all')
```